# Getting cyclic object value error in React

Tags: reactjs

My Code looks like this. What i am trying to achieve is when upvote is clicked, the upvote should be updated without reloading the page

```
const Button = ({ onClick, text }) => (
  <button onClick={onClick}>{text}</button>
);

const Blog = ({ blog , updateUpvote}) => {
  const [detailsVisible, setDetailsVisible] = useState(false);

  const toggleDetails = () => {
    setDetailsVisible(!detailsVisible);
  };


  const blogStyle = {
    paddingTop: 10,
    paddingLeft: 2,
    border: 'solid',
    borderWidth: 1,
    marginBottom: 5
  }

  return (
    <div style={blogStyle}>
      <p>
        {blog.title} {blog.author}
        <Button 
          onClick={toggleDetails} 
          text={detailsVisible ? 'Hide Details' : 'Show Details'}
        />
      </p>
      {detailsVisible && (
        <div>
          <p>{blog.url}</p>
          <div>
            upvotes: {blog.upvotes} 
            <Button 
              text={"upvote"}
              onClick={updateUpvote} />
          </div>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
```

The updateUpvote is defined withing App component and passed as prop as

```
  const updateUpvote = async (blog) => {
    try {
      const updatedBlog = await blogService.update(blog.id, {
        ...blog,
        upvotes: blog.upvotes + 1
      });
      // Update the state in the parent component
      setBlogs((prevBlogs) =>
        prevBlogs.map((b) => (b.id === updatedBlog.id ? updatedBlog : b))
      );

      console.log(updatedBlog)
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  const blogList = () => (
    blogs.map(blog => (
      <Blog key={blog.id} blog={blog} updateUpvote={updateUpvote}/>
    ))
  );
```

I am getting TypeError: cyclic object value error when i click the upvote button defined inside Blog component. I have not been able to figure out what the issue is. updateUpvote is only defined inside App component and Blog component is outside of App component.

Answer (score 0):

It was really silly error from my side. I was not sending any argument to updateUpvote function. New updated part looks like below

```
        <div>
          <p>{blog.url}</p>
          <div>
            upvotes: {blog.upvotes} 
            <Button 
              text={"upvote"}
              onClick={() => updateUpvote(blog)} />
          </div>
        </div>
```